# The security of private key with geth on the server-side

Tags: go-ethereum, security, private-key

If you initiate a transaction in real time, you need to store the private key on the geth server to initiate the transaction. Once the geth server is hacked, the private key may be leaked. Is there any good way to use the private key to initiate a transaction, but there is no danger of the private key being leaked?

Hope you can give me some help, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The best way to do it is not to have private keys on the server-side. Most Ethereum decentralised applications have their keys in client-side wallets and there is very little need for so-called hot wallets.

A good approach is to minimize the risk of compromised keys. Make sure that the key does not hold any balance and is basically almost worthless for anyone compromising it. For example, in the mining use case, withdraw balance from the server every day to a safe cold wallet, so you can lose max daily profits in the case the server is hacked.